# merge is not working in adding data in array in twig

Tags: php, symfony

what i need

- i need to merge more then two values in array.

twig code

```
 {% set upcoming_event=page_param.month_data.0.upcoming_event %}
{{upcoming_event}}//212333
{% set ongoing_event='' %}//null or empty

 {% set pages= page_param.page|merge({(upcoming_event): ongoing_event}) %}

{% set meta_array=Title('event_listing',pages) %}
```

o/p

```
    Array
(
[industry_url] => 
[country_url] => 
[city_url] => 
[event_type] => 
[0]=>
 )
```

- it should merge upcoming event values and ongoing also .
- i have reffered  docs : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html
- o/p should it should be

  ```
   Array
  (
    [industry_url] => 
    [country_url] => 
   [city_url] => 
    [event_type] => 
  [upcming]=>233
   [ongoing]=>null
  ```

  )

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
{% set pages= page_param.page|merge({(upcoming_event): ongoing_event}) %}
```

looks wrong. You're actually adding only one value with `upcoming_event` as the key and `ongoing_event` as the value.

To get the desired result, replace the mentioned line with:

```
{% set pages= page_param.page|merge({'upcoming': upcoming_event, 'ongoing': ongoing_event}) %}
```